# Final step for completing a search engine in python(pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, search-engine

I have a dictionary which basically stores all the words present in a big Dataframe(a lot of rows and 12 columns), the dictionary looks like this:

```
    vocabulary = {'hello':[3,1998,876,3888], 'beautiful':[677, 4, 56],......}
```

Where the values are the rows of the dataFrame in which the word is present.

What I want to do is, take a string(query) as input,

```
    query = 'a beautiful house with big windows'
```

return certain columns (let's call them A, B, C, D) of the Dataframe only of the rows that contain all the words of the input sentence. 
I've already preprocessed the data (stemming, stopwords, remove punctuation...) for the vocabulary and for the input query.
Anyone could help me? Thank you

Comment: If that is the query you want to answer, it makes much more sense to invert your dictionary to be `vocabulary = {3:["hello","a", "house"], 677:["big", "hello"],......}`. From there it would be trivial to execute this query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to check each word in the `query` sentence, find which rows those words appear in (from the `vocabulary` dict), and return the rows which are common for *all* the words in the query. If so this is one solution (I've simplified your example):

```
vocabulary = {'hello':[3,1998,876,3888], 'beautiful':[677, 4, 56, 3, 876]}
query = 'hello beautiful'
words = set(query.split())
rows = [vocabulary[w] for w in words]
common_rows = rows[0]
for r in rows[1:]:
    common_rows = list(set(common_rows) & set(r))
print(common_rows)
```

> [3, 876]

To select the rows from the DataFrame you then just need to do:

`df.loc[common_rows, ["A", "B", "C", "D"]]`

Comment: Yes! We're almost there. But I expressed my self wrong. The values in the `vocabulary` aren't actually the row indexes, but something very close: it's the index+1 but it's stored in another column, it's not the actul index. So if i want my new df i should do something like:

        `newDf=pd.DataFrame([])`
        `for elem in common_rows:`
            `newDf = newDf.append(data.loc[data['title'] == elem])`

But of course it's not working. It's giving me an empty df.

Comment: If the output of my code (`common_rows`) is in another column in the DataFrame, you can just do: `df.loc[df["other_col_name"].isin(common_rows), ["A", "B", "C", "D"]]`

Comment: the idea is correct but this is giving me as a result an empty dataFrame. And I'm sure the problem is not with the original df since it is full of data.

Comment: Can you post an example of the data in the column which contains the index+1 numbers? Are you sure it's of data type integer?

Comment: Thank you! you wer right! it wasn't a int, had to cast the value. Thank you again!

Comment: No problem! Glad you got it sorted